# CSS change in an addEventListener function is not applied unitl the function exits

Tags: javascript, css

Im trying to change the cursor logo when Im building a dynamic div. Depending on how much data it can take up a few seconds to load so I need the cursor change.

The problem Im having is that the cursor isnt changing until my code has fully executed.

Im have a dynamically generated chart with the points in the chart set to popup more data when they are clicked. This is the eventListener Ive created and it works fine apart from my CSS update not getting applied until it has exited the function.

Any idea how I can force it to update immediately

```
    point.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {

          document.body.className = 'waiting';
var evtPoint        = document.getElementById(evt.currentTarget.id);
          var index           = evtPoint.id.substring(evtPoint.id.lastIndexOf('-') + 1, evtPoint.id.length);
          var chartOptions    = Charts.options[elementId];


          var txnData     = chartOptions.data.txn[index];
          var txnFullData = chartOptions.data.txnFull;
          var theDate         = new Date(txnData.time);


          // pop up
          var txnsPerMinutePopUp       = document.getElementById('txnsPerMinutePopUp');
          txnsPerMinutePopUp.innerHTML = '<div id = "txnsPerMinutePopUp-bg"></div>' +
                                                 '<div id = "txnsPerMinutePopUp-body">' +
                                                 '<div id = "txnsPerMinutePopUp-body-heading"></div>' +
                                                 '<div id = "txnsPerMinutePopUp-body-txns">';


          var txnsPerMinutePopUpHeading = document.getElementById('txnsPerMinutePopUp-body-heading');
          var txnsPerMinutePopUpBody    = document.getElementById('txnsPerMinutePopUp-body-txns');





          function addZero(i) {
            if (i < 10) {
              i = '0' + i;
            }
            return i;
          }

          for (var i = 0; i < txnFullData.length; i++) {

           // console.log("loop" + i, txnFullData);
            var date = new Date(txnFullData[i].time);
            if (date.getTime() === theDate.getTime()) {

              txnsPerMinutePopUpHeading.innerHTML = '<div class="txnsPerMinutePopUp-body-heading-title">Tweets</div><div class="txnsPerMinutePopUp-body-heading-time">' + addZero(theDate.getHours()) + ':' + addZero(theDate.getMinutes()) + '</div>';

              var child = '<div class = "txnsPerMinutePopUp-txns">' +
                          '<div class = "txnsPerMinutePopUp-txns-img">' +
                          '<object data = "' + txnFullData[i].profile_image_url + '" class = "border-rad-25 cross-series-profile-img" width = "50px" height = "50px" type = "image/jpeg">' +
                          '<img src = "assets/img/engager_profile_default-47.svg" class = "border-rad-25 cross-series-profile-img" width = "50px" height = "50px" alt = "' + txnFullData[i].screen_name + ' profile image" />' +
                          '</object>' +
                          '</div>' +
                          '<div class = "txnsPerMinutePopUp-txns-screen-name">' +
                          '<a href = "https://txn.com/@' + txnFullData[i].screen_name + '" target = "_blank">@' + txnFullData[i].screen_name + '</a>' +
                          '</div>' +
                          '<div class = "txnsPerMinutePopUp-txns-text">' + Charts.lineChart.parseText(txnFullData[i].text) + '</div>' +
                          '</div>';

              txnsPerMinutePopUpBody.innerHTML += child;



            }
          }

          txnsPerMinutePopUp.innerHTML += '</div>' +
                                                  '</div>';

          //document.body.style.cursor='default';

          txnsPerMinutePopUp.style.visibility = 'visible';

          var bg = document.getElementById('txnsPerMinutePopUp-bg');
          bg.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
            txnsPerMinutePopUp.style.visibility = 'hidden';
          });

    }, false);
```

My CSS then is just

```
body.waiting * { cursor: wait; }
```

**UPDATE**

From researching potential causes I found out that most browsers wont update the DOM immediately and I need to interrupt the javascript to allow for the DOM to get updated.

Ive updated my code to move the bulk of the operations out to a separate function and tried to set a timeout value on it and its still not updating the cursor until everything completes.

I also tried to add a mousedown event to try and get ahead of the javascript in the  on click but it didnt work either

**EventListener**

```
    point.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {

      //document.body.className = 'waiting';

      // setTimeout(function() {
        Charts.lineChart.changeCursor();
      // },10);

      var evtPoint        = document.getElementById(evt.currentTarget.id);
      var index           = evtPoint.id.substring(evtPoint.id.lastIndexOf('-') + 1, evtPoint.id.length);
      var chartOptions    = Charts.options[elementId];


      var txnData     = chartOptions.data.txn[index];
      var txnFullData = chartOptions.data.txnFull;
      var theDate         = new Date(txnData.time);


      function addZero(i) {
        if (i < 10) {
          i = '0' + i;
        }
        return i;
      }

       setTimeout(function() {
          Charts.lineChart.breakOut( txnFullData,theDate );
       },100);


      document.body.style.cursor='default';

      txnsPerMinuteTweetsPopUp.style.visibility = 'visible';



    }, false);
```

and the following code was moved into the breakout function

**breakOut**

```
 Charts.lineChart.breakOut = function(txnFullData,theDate){

    function addZero(i) {
      if (i < 10) {
        i = '0' + i;
      }
      return i;
    }

    var txnsPerMinutePopUp       = document.getElementById('txnsPerMinutePopUp');
    txnsPerMinutePopUp.innerHTML = '<div id = "txnsPerMinutePopUp-bg"></div>' +
      '<div id = "txnsPerMinutePopUp-body">' +
      '<div id = "txnsPerMinutePopUp-body-heading"></div>' +
      '<div id = "txnsPerMinutePopUp-body-txns">';


    var txnsPerMinutePopUpHeading = document.getElementById('txnsPerMinutePopUp-body-heading');
    var txnsPerMinutePopUpBody    = document.getElementById('txnsPerMinutePopUp-body-txns');

    for (var i = 0; i < txnFullData.length; i++) {

      // console.log("loop" + i, txnFullData);
      var date = new Date(txnFullData[i].time);
      if (date.getTime() === theDate.getTime()) {

        txnsPerMinutePopUpHeading.innerHTML = '<div class="txnsPerMinutePopUp-body-heading-title">Tweets</div><div class="txnsPerMinutePopUp-body-heading-time">' + addZero(theDate.getHours()) + ':' + addZero(theDate.getMinutes()) + '</div>';

        var child = '<div class = "txnsPerMinutePopUp-txns">' +
          '<div class = "txnsPerMinutePopUp-txns-img">' +
          '<object data = "' + txnFullData[i].profile_image_url + '" class = "border-rad-25 cross-series-profile-img" width = "50px" height = "50px" type = "image/jpeg">' +
          '<img src = "assets/img/engager_profile_default-47.svg" class = "border-rad-25 cross-series-profile-img" width = "50px" height = "50px" alt = "' + txnFullData[i].screen_name + ' profile image" />' +
          '</object>' +
          '</div>' +
          '<div class = "txnsPerMinutePopUp-txns-screen-name">' +
          '<a href = "https://txn.com/@' + txnFullData[i].screen_name + '" target = "_blank">@' + txnFullData[i].screen_name + '</a>' +
          '</div>' +
          '<div class = "txnsPerMinutePopUp-txns-text">' + Charts.lineChart.parseText(txnFullData[i].text) + '</div>' +
          '</div>';

        txnsPerMinutePopUpBody.innerHTML += child;



      }
    }

    txnsPerMinutePopUp.innerHTML += '</div>' +
      '</div>';

    var bg = document.getElementById('txnsPerMinutePopUp-bg');
    bg.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
      txnsPerMinutePopUp.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    });

}
```

Comment: I'm struggling to figure out a route around this. I've found a number of questions pointing to this issue without any solution. It's specifically the `cursor` that's not working, within the same event other things can be changed, `background-color` and such, and they work, but the cursor is blocked from updating until the mouse button is released.